# List<T> override toArray ends up as T1[] toArray

Tags: java, android

I am trying to tweak a List a bit by implementing the List interface in a class.

I can override and implement all methods with no problem, except this one:

```
<T> T[] toArray(T[] a);
```

Android Studio shows me this code when overriding, creating a new type `T1`.
Why is that and what effect does it have?

```
@NonNull
@Override
public <T1> T1[] toArray(@NonNull T1[] a) {
    return inner.toArray(a);
}
```

When hovering over the `a` parameter, I see this lint warning:

> Array of type `java.lang.Object` expected

When I try to change it by hand back to `T[]` instead of `T1[]` I get this error:

> toArray(T[])' in 'QueryList' clashes with 'toArray(T[])' in 'java.util.List'; both methods have same erasure, yet neither overrides the other

Is this a bug in Android Studio/intelliJ that it can't create that override correctly or do I miss something?

**Edit:**
Here is the declaration of the class, including `T` and where it is used.

```
public class QueryList<T> implements List<T> {

//<editor-fold desc="inner list & constructors">
protected final List<T> inner;

public QueryList() {
    inner = new ArrayList<>();
}

public QueryList(int initialCapacity) {
    inner = new ArrayList<>(initialCapacity);
}

public QueryList(@NonNull Collection<? extends T> c) {
    inner = new ArrayList<>(c);
}
//</editor-fold>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please show us the declaration of `inner`. Thanks.

Comment: ``protected final List<T> inner;`` and in the constructor instanciated as ``new ArrayList<>();``

Comment: I'm guessing you have another type parameter in an enclosing class that is also named `T`?

Comment: @JornVernee please see my edit above. I posted the class declaration & constructors. No other T involved, no other overrides.

Comment: @Grisgram _"No other T involved"_ Your `QueryList` class declares a type parameter that is also named `T`, so intellij probably renames the one in the override to `T1` to explicitly show that it is distinct.

Comment: I do not understand this comment. ``<T>`` of QueryList MUST BE ``<T>`` of List. It is the same, not "another" type parameter. Only one T exists. Can you please explain that a bit more? Maybe I miss something syntactical here?

Comment: Jorn Vernee nailed it. I'm not sure why the `List` interface defines the `toArray` method like it does, but it is using a *different* type parameter then the one from the List interface. So you are allowed to do the following:
`Integer[] array = new ArrayList<String>().toArray(new Integer[0]);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> No other T involved

Your `QueryList` class declares a type parameter that is also named `T`, so intellij probably renames the one in the override to `T1` to explicitly show that it is distinct.

Note that [`toArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray(T%5B%5D)) in `List` also declares it's own type parameter, and that is also needed for a correct override:

```
<T> T[] toArray(T[] a);
^^^
```

I'm guessing your fix also removed the type parameter declaration like this:

```
T[] toArray(T[] a);
```

But that would no longer make it an override, because the type parameters have to match. As per [jls 8.4.8.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1):

> An instance method mC declared in or inherited by class C, overrides from C another method mA declared in class A, iff all of the following are true:
>
> ...
>
> - The signature of mC is a subsignature [(§8.4.2)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2) of the signature of mA.

And in `8.4.2`:

> Two methods or constructors, M and N, have the same signature if they have the same name, **the same type parameters (if any)** [(§8.4.4)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6), and, after adapting the formal parameter types of N to the the type parameters of M, the same formal parameter types.

And the concept of sub-signature is not any more lenient on the emphasized part.

---

When I change it to `<T> T[] toArray(T[] a);`, I get a warning that the type parameter `T` declared there is hiding the one from the enclosing class, but changing the name to `T1` makes that go away.

As to why the signature is like that, one explanation is that you'd want to use a super-type array to collect the elements of the list. e.g.:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}

List<B> list = ...
A[] elements = list.toArray(new A[0]); // should still work, no need to pass a `B[]` strictly.
```

Comment: Yeah. If you examine `java.util.ArrayList`, for example. you'll see that the class type parameter is `E` (`ArrayList<E> implements List<E>`), but <T> is specific to this `T[] toArray(T[] a)` method. There's also `Object[] toArray()` method, but no `E[] toArray()`

Comment: Thank you very much for all the quick replies!